# GPT-2's encoder.py and train.py are not working

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, gpt-2

I'm trying to train GPT-2 to use what I provide in a text file, napoleon.txt. When I run the encoder, it seems to work from the command prompt.

```
python encoder.py napoleon.txt napoleon.npz
```

It doesn't, however, actually create napoleon.npz. But this is only part of the problem. The larger issue is that train.py, what I actually need in order to train GPT-2, spits out an error every single time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .dataset import Corpus, EncodedDataset
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I've tried every single solution I found on the internet and that I could think of, but I'm stuck. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation:
https://github.com/openai/gpt-2-output-dataset/tree/master/detector

You're expected to run it as `python -m detector.train`.